# Java Class Extension?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have 3 classes called

- *Student* (has `name`, `grade`, `student number`)
- *Master Student* (has same fields with *Student* also it has `thesistopic`)
- and *Phd Student* (has same fields with *Master Student* class also it has `scolarship` amount)

Phd Student and Master Student are different from each other.
But Phd Student class has everything in the Master Student.

Which one is true

- These classes extend Student separataly?
- MasterStudent extend Student and PhdStudent extend MasterStudent?

Comment: What do you think and why do you think so?

Comment: please add the code please..

Comment: I think Master and phd extend student seperately.Because a student can't be phd and master at the same time.

Comment: Does `extends Student` show up in any of this source code? (Also, "Master Student" and "Phd Student" are illegal class names.)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, both statements are true. Since student is the lowest tier, anything above could extend student. Master Student is the mid tier, and phd is the highest. So master would extend student and phd would extend master which is an extension of student. So to reiterate, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

In case of inheritance, the rule of thumb is that you only use it when it is useful.

In case of MAster : PHD I don't see one method, which probably / possibly has a different implementation (or could have so in the future) being sufficient enough reason to restrict yourself to inheriting.

I would opt for inheriting from student separately to keep the most flexibility for future expansion(s).